# MVC Code Igniter 403 Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-403, codeigniter-routing

Hello all i am new to MVC and after attempting a **mod_rewrite** i am having trouble with **403** when i attempt to load `site/about`. I have my project in the main root directory of my web server `htdocs`, i have struggled to understand many of the tutorials online. The error is;

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while 
trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

site - controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $data['title']= "Welcome Learn Guitar Online";
    //$this->load->view('home',$data);
    //$this->getValues();
    $this->load->view("about",$data);

}
}
```

about.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<h1>Welcome to about</h1>
<div id="body">
    <p>hello</p>
</div>

<p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

config file variables

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/index.php';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempt to load `site/about`. but as I seen your code there is no function named as `about`. You just need to call your controller i.e. `http://localhost/FOLDER_NAME/site` and default it will call `index` function and load the `about.php` view.

Your `config.php` should like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/FOLDER_NAME';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

If you have put your `ht.access` inside your project folder than there is no need to define `base_url()` also.

Answer (score 0):

can you try making the `.htaccess` to this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /FOLDER_NAME/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

in `Config`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/FOLDER_NAME';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Replace FOLDER_NAME with your folder name. Now you should be able to access your url without index.php